# memory warnings and white screen

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-warning

My universal iOS app dies upon receiving memory warnings. Actually it just do the default behaviour - current visible view controller releases its views and I see just blank underneath app window instead. So the question is - what techniques should I adopt to prevent this default behaviour?

And what should I release if I don't have such resources as cached data or images in memory? Other's view controllers' views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that was because I didn't set up root controller for navigation controller properly. Actually, there was view inside another view of root view controller. Silly mistake...